# Force SSL on your website using .htaccess and Forcing the "www." at the beginning of URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, web, https

I was using this code and it successfully forces ssl:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

however it does not force www at the begining of urls. I got this supposed solution posted on another page here:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But what i get when i attempt to open my page is this:"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

How may i fix this, that is, not only force ssl but also force www at the beginning of urls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, example.com  is not redirected to   https://www.example.com, but rather this https://example.com. I need a solution that will Forcing the "www." at the beginning of ssl URLs.

Comment: @MichelMzer There is something else that is causing that redirect. There is no possibility these rules will redirect to anything that doesn't start with `www.`. These rules work fine in my blank htaccess file.